# splitResults option shows unknown in apache camel google-sheets-stream component

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

I'm using apache camel google-sheets-stream component to read google sheet and it is working fine, but I want to split the body into rows and columns, there is an option called "splitResults" given in camel doc, but when I'm using that option it throws "unknown parameters" error.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Below is my camel route:

```
from uri="google-sheets-stream://spreadsheets?accessToken=MY_TOKEN_HERE&amp;clientId=MY_CLIENT_ID&amp;clientSecret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&amp;applicationName=CamelGoogleApp&amp;refreshToken=1/zwgy73W-pcNoCtbOxs_t4b0&amp;spreadsheetId=1hkw_0oOaQDIRZVX_19LpywE&amp;range=Form Responses 1"
```

Camel Doc that I followed :

> https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-google-sheets/src/main/docs/google-sheets-stream-component.adoc

Camel google-sheet Version: 2.24.1

Log:

```
There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{splitResults=true}]
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:209)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1143)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3729)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3443)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:209)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3251)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3247)
```

Comment: You probably want to remove your access tokens from question (you should never post tchem online).

Comment: This is debated on the Camel mailing list, and its because he is using an older Camel version from Red Hat Fuse that dont have that option in the component.